# Android dynamic Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'd like to call different Intents from one class in stead of making multiple classes. How can I handle this?

I have the standard code already:

```
public static void classIntent(String title, String message) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(currentContext, OtherActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(currentContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(currentContext)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.btn_marker)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(intent).build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Which responds to this:

```
notificationIntent("Title", "Message");
```

To do what I want, the respond needs to be changed to:

```
notificationIntent("Title", "Message", INTENT);
```

What steps do I need to take? Something like:

```
public static void classIntent(String title, String message, Intent i) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(currentContext, ImmediateActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivities(currentContext, 0, new Intent[] { i }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: `String title, String message` you passed to the `classIntent` method is never used.

Comment: Hello Apurva. I did not uploaded the complete code, I have now. I don't have problems with the title and the message. My focus is on the Intent

Comment: Nobody knows the answer? :(